# HTTP Pino logger and Elastic Common Schema (ecs) format in NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, elk, pinojs, elastic-common-schema

I am trying to apply [@elastic/ecs-pino-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/ecs-pino-format) to [nestjs-pino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-pino). Under the good nestjs-pino is using `http-pino`. I have noticed that `http-pino` adds the request object inside `[Symbol(pino.chindings)]` and I am assuming it's using a child logger.So I tried to write a custom formatter for extracting the req by calling `obj.res.log.bindings()` and putting at `http.request` to be compliant with **Elastic Common Schema (ecs)**. The problem I face is now my log contains duplicate the `req` and the `http.request` and can't find a way to remove it. Not sure if I am looking in the wrong direction but I have found a lot of issues trying to make [nestjs-pino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-pino) print **Elastic Common Schema (ecs)** format logs. Also I have noticed issues where  [@elastic/ecs-pino-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/ecs-pino-format) can't handle fastify. Has anyone had similar issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was confused with `pino` and `pino-http` and how they were integrated in [nestjs-pino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-pino). From the looks of it  [@elastic/ecs-pino-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/ecs-pino-format) doesn't handle all the specifics for **Elastic Common Schema (ecs)** in `pino-http`. So what I ended up doing was passing in `nestjs-pino` as a configuration a merge of the format object from [@elastic/ecs-pino-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/ecs-pino-format) and configuring `pino-http`.

`pino-http` supports passing

```js
customAttributeKeys: {
req: 'http.request',
res: 'http.response',
}
```

for changing the keys of `req` and `res`. As for the data that `req` and `res` contain, `http-pino` has another option for transforming them

```js
serializers: {
req: (log) => {... return transform },
res: (log) => {... return transform },
}
```

For more information about [pino HTTP options](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-http#logger-options).

Hope this helps anyone facing the same problem or want nestjs with **Elastic Common Schema (ecs)** logs.

An [example configuration](https://gist.github.com/gkampitakis/b36819f38f8886598c20ed1af7245e3a) passed to `http-pino` for having ECS format.

Comment: Hey Georgios, any chance you could share a snippet of how you achieved this? I'm trying to do the exact same thing and it's not immediately obvious how to do so while still getting all the nestjs-pino features.

Comment: You can create a configuration like this and pass it to nestjs-pino options. https://gist.github.com/gkampitakis/b36819f38f8886598c20ed1af7245e3a

Comment: One comment is the Error passed to "formatError" should be "err" and not "error", though I'm not sure if this my setup vs. yours.